# Calculating years from 2 dates

Tags: sql, oracle

I am running on an oracle database. I want to find all those recipients that were treated before they reached 25 of age. I know that there are at least 500, but the result I get is 0. Obviously my query is wrong. So I think the issue is with the way I subtract the dates. They both are of type date in the table. From what I see, it should be possible to just subtract two dates?
Some write that they use DATEDIFF, but this does not work for me.

```
   select count(*) FROM V_Persons
    where exists(select * from res_tx res, recipient rec, Treatment tr
                where (tr.TREAT_DATE - rec.DATE_OF_BIRTH) < 25 
                and rec.ident = res.ident
                and rec.ident = tr.ident)
```

Comment: You can just subtract two dates but basic arithmatic on dates in Oracle gives answers in days.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this to troubleshoot if the date difference is working as you expect it to in the query inside the exists subquery.

```
select * , (tr.TREAT_DATE - rec.DATE_OF_BIRTH ) as DateDifference
 from res_tx res, recipient rec, Treatment tr
                where (tr.TREAT_DATE - rec.DATE_OF_BIRTH) < 25 
                and rec.ident = res.ident
                and rec.ident = tr.ident
```

Comment: `date_a - date_b` gives the difference in days between the two dates - so this is checking if there was a difference of **25 days** between the dates not years.

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM   V_Persons p
WHERE  EXISTS(
  SELECT 'X'
  FROM   recipient c
         INNER JOIN Treatment r
         ON ( c.ident = r.ident )
         INNER JOIN res_tx s       -- Do you need to join this table?
         ON ( c.ident = s.ident )
  WHERE  r.TREAT_DATE < ADD_MONTHS( c.DATE_OF_BIRTH, 25 * 12 )
  AND    p.ident = c.ident         -- You need to correlate with the outer query.
);
```